# Check if it is a geometric random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-series, density-function

A system used to read electric meters automatically requires the use of a 64-bit computer message. Occasionally random interference causes a digit reversal resulting in a transmission error. assume that the probability of a digit reversal for each bit is 1/2000. Let X denote the number of transmission errors per 64-bit message sent. Is X geometric?

Comment: If the errors are independent (unlikely!) then the distribution of $X$ is binomial, but the Poisson will give a reasonable approximation.

Comment: The number of errors in a single transmission is indeed binomial if errors are independent. But the number of transmissions until the transmission is correct (assuming erroneous transmissions are somehow flagged and re-attempted) is indeed geometric.

Answer (score 1):

There is a finite upper bound on the number of bit reversals in a $64$-bit message.  If $X$ is geometrically distributed, then $\Pr(X>x)>0$ no matter how big $x$ is; there is no finite upper bound.  Such a random variable is distributed as the number of trials needed to get one success, or as the number of failures before the first success.